# Accessing to objects of a dynamic way in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have the following class based view in which I perform to queryset:

```
class PatientDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = PatientProfile
    template_name = 'patient_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'patientdetail'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context=super(PatientDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        queryset= RehabilitationSession.objects.filter(patient__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        context.update({'patient_session_data': queryset,})
    return context
```

When I acces the value of `patient_session_data` key sent, in my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {{patient_session_data}}
 {% endblock content %}
```

I get this the `QuerySet` object:

```
<QuerySet [<RehabilitationSession: Hernando Zambrano Cuellar>, <RehabilitationSession: Hernando Zambrano Cuellar>, <RehabilitationSession: Hernando Zambrano Cuellar>]>
```

I want access to specific attibute named `upper_extremity` of my `RehabilitationSession` model, then I make this:

```
{% for upperlimb in patient_session_data %}
    {{upperlimb.upper_extremity}} 
{%endfor%}
```

And I get this in my template:

```
Izquierda Izquierda Izquierda
```

This mean, three times the value, because my queryset return me three objects. This is logic.

For access to value of a separate way I make this in my template:

```
{{patient_session_data.0.upper_extremity}}
```

And I get: `Izquierda`

**My goal**

I unknown the amount of `querysets objects` RehabilitationSession that will be returned by the queryset executed in my `PatientDetail` cbv, because the number is dynamic, may be any amount of objects returned.

I want read the value content of each `patient_session_data` `upper_extremity` and accord to the value make something in my template,

But I want read it of a dynamic way,without use `{{patient_session_data.<0-1-2-3>.upper_extremity}}`

For example in a hypotetical case:

```
#if all objects returned have same value in upper_extremity 
{% if patient_session_data.upper_extremity == 'Izquierda' %}
   <div class="col-md-10">
      <h5>Segmentos corporales a tratar</h5>
      <small>Codo - mano - falange</small>
   </div>                                           
{%endif%}
```

I think that I have count the amount of objects and make with them some actions, because I don't have clear ...
How to can I access of a individual way to the objects returned of a dynamic way without matter the objects number returned?

---

**UPDATE**

I did have not taken into account the possibility of that  all objects returned have different value in upper_extremity. This mean that I wish that when the queryset objects returned have a mix of values of `Izquierda` `Derecha` `Izquierda` also make something.

In this moment (with the support provided by [@2ps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6043170/2ps) when the querysets objects all have `upper_extremity='Izquierda'` make something and when the querysets objects all have `upper_extremity='Derecha'` make something.

Is want perform some actions when the values of `upper_extremity` of the querysets objects may be:

Object queryset 1: `upper_extremity='Derecha'`

Object queryset 2:`upper_extremity='Izquierda'`

Object queryset 3:`upper_extremity='Derecha'` 
. ..
and so...

According to the solution of [@2ps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6043170/2ps) I think that the core of this assesment is in:

```
# Perform a set union with the values of 'upper_extremity' attribute for remove the repeated values(Izquierda and Derecha) and distinct them
upper_extremities = set(queryset.values_list('upper_extremity', flat=True).distinct())

# Create a empty dict like data destiny
all_match = dict()

# Iterate on all values possible
for value in ('Izquierda', 'Derecha', ): # add any other values you want here

    # Fill the dictionary always that the longitude of upper_extremities (values get) be equal to 1 (?) 
    all_match[value] = value in upper_extremities and len(upper_extremities) == 1

# Send the result to the template
context['all_match'] = all_match
```

In my template I think ...

```
{% if all_match.Izquierda and all_match.Derecha %}
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <h5>Segmentos corporales a tratar</h5>
      <small>Codo - mano - falange</small>
    </div>
{%endif%}
```

How to can I cover this another scenary when the objects querysets have a mix of upper_extremity values (`Derecha` and `Izquierda`)

Thanks and excuse me for the new question, I have not clear this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several possible approaches you can take here.  For the all `izquierda` or all `derecha`, here is what you can do:

```
class PatientDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = PatientProfile
    template_name = 'patient_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'patientdetail'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context=super(PatientDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        queryset= RehabilitationSession.objects.filter(patient__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        context['patient_session_data'] = queryset
        # get a list of all upper extremities
        upper_extremities = set(queryset.values_list('upper_extremity', flat=True).distinct())
        all_match = dict()
        for value in ('Izquierda', 'Derecha', ): # add any other values you want here
            all_match[value] = value in upper_extremities and len(upper_extremities) == 1
        context['all_match'] = all_match
        return context
```

And in your template

```
#if all objects returned have same value in upper_extremity 
{% if all_match.Izquierda or all_match.Derecha %}
   <div class="col-md-10">
      <h5>Segmentos corporales a tratar</h5>
      <small>Codo - mano - falange</small>
   </div>                                           
{%else%}
{# here we handle all cases with mixed results #}
{%endif%}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the great answer @2ps,  I did have not taken into account the possibility of that all objects returned have different value in `upper_extremity`.  Do you can see **my update** in my question please?. My apologies for the awkwardness

Comment: @bgarcial:  see the updated answer.  All you need to do is add an `else` block in your template and you can handle mixed left/right cases.  The only corner case here is (1) values that we did not cover (i.e., there values other than Izquierda or Derecha for upper_extremity) or (2) 0 results in the queryset.  I assumed you handled (2) elsewhere in your template.